# How to get string between two tags

Tags: regex, string

I would like to get `demo` object from string file:

But looks like that my regexp is wrong: `(demo: \[)(.*)(\],)`

```
sayHello(() => ({
    foo: eeeeeeeeeeeeee,
    demo: [
        {
            name: 'abcd', 
        },
        {
            name: 'qqqq', 
        },
    ],
}));
```

Expected output:

```
[
        {
            name: 'abcd', 
        },
        {
            name: 'qqqq', 
        },
]
```

Comment: It seems you are trying to parse a JS file - that can be very tricky and almost impossible unless you are absolutely _sure_ that there cannot be a `]` inside this object elsewhere, for example. You also need to know that `.*` does _not_ match newlines, you need to use `[\s\S]*` for that. If you can't be sure, I would recommend using a parser like acorn to _actually_ semantically parse the file as JavaScript.

Comment: It was misstake, I edited after few second

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/g0iheb/1 - This will only work if the demo: object does not contain any nested objects in it. If you have different test cases, please let us know.